# Stencil-like shader masking, but with shader control over how the mask is created?

Tags: opengl, glsl

What I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Draw geometry with backface culling disabled, and with a clip plane defined, such that the geometry is clipped and the drawn backfaces fill in the exposed interior to create a mask.
2. Then in another pass, render a quad which exactly matches the position of the clip plane, using a mask from the first pass to cover only the exposed holes with a textured surface, giving the illusion that the geometry is properly modified.
3. The clipped geometry may create multiple separated holes, so I can't just draw the plane over top without masking.

I can get part of the way there in the shader, testing `gl_FrontFacing` to see which pixels are over an exposed interior. However, I can't find a way to record this for a later pass.

My first thought was to use the stencil buffer, which would work great for constraining the second pass, but as far as I can tell there's no way for a shader to selectively write to it.

The only other thing that comes to mind is to use a framebuffer and have the shader write to an extra output buffer, and then feed that back in to the second pass to do the filtering manually. But:

1. How would I know what part of the texture to sample? I assume I'd need to calculate screen positions of vertices, pass that to the interpolated by the fragment shader, and test/discard from there?
2. Is there a better or perhaps more automatic (similar to stencil buffer) way to accomplish this?

Comment: "calculate screen positions of vertices..." this is what `gl_FragCoord` is for.

Comment: Why not just render only the backfaces to the stencil buffer? That is, instead of turning off culling, *flip* culling.

Comment: @NicolBolas Interesting idea, I didn't think of that. I'll have to give that a try!